# Return Rowindex for matched column values

Tags: vb.net

I am trying the following code which compares 2 datatables and returns `IEnumerable<String>` of non-matching values based on **ID_2** and **ID** columns.

```
Invalid_IDs = dt1.AsEnumerable() _
.Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("ID_2")) _
.Except(dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("ID")))
```

Now, instead of getting the *ID_2* value as output, I want the indexes of the non-matching values from *ID_2* and *ID*.

Comment: The `Select` method is overloaded, so instead of using `Function(row)` you can use `Function(row, index)` and then use `index` in the output.

Comment: @jmcilhinney can you give an example?

Comment: What do you not understand about the examples you found when you looked for them yourself?

Comment: BTW, VB code is not "script". It's code.

Comment: OT, there's no need to use line continuation characters in that code. As long as your physical line ends with something that cannot legally be the end of a line of code, the compiler will assume that you're continuing on the next line. In your case, if you put the dot at the end of the previous line instead of the start of the next line, the line continuation characters will be unnecessary. Note that that is how it's been done in Tim's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overload of `Select` gives you the index. You could use a `Lookup(Of TKey, TValue)`(for performance reasons) to find missing id's and their indexes in table1 and table2:

```
Dim dt1IdLookup = dt1.AsEnumerable().
        Select(Function(row, ix) (ID:=row.Field(Of String)("ID_2"),IX:=ix)).
        ToLookup(Function(x) x.ID)
Dim dt2IdLookup = dt1.AsEnumerable().
        Select(Function(row, ix) (ID:=row.Field(Of String)("ID"),IX:=ix)).
        ToLookup(Function(x) x.ID)

Dim missingIdsAndIndexesInTable1 = dt2IdLookup.
        Where(Function(x) Not dt1IdLookup.Contains(x.Key)).
        Select(Function(x) (ID:=x.Key, Indexes:=x.Select(Function(y) y.IX).ToList()))
Dim missingIdsAndIndexesInTable2 = dt1IdLookup.
        Where(Function(x) Not dt2IdLookup.Contains(x.Key)).
        Select(Function(x) (ID:=x.Key, Indexes:=x.Select(Function(y) y.IX).ToList()))
```

Now you could for example use a simple loop to process them:

```
For Each x In missingIdsAndIndexesInTable1
    Dim id As String = x.ID
    Dim indexes As List(Of Int32) = x.Indexes
Next
```